FAILED TO LOAD SSL KEYSTORE OF TYPE JKS - JMeter
I am trying to setup producer with the help of Di KafkaMeter Plugin and below are configs
SCRAM-SHA-512, SASL_SSl, Jaas File, truststore file/Password and No Keystore
Although, I am keeping keystore argument as blank, I am getting “FAILED TO LOAD SSL KEYSTORE OF TYPE JKS” “java.nio.file.accessdeniedexception”
I think the plugin needs both valid keystore and truststore file. I do have pem file, but not sure on how to use it in JMeter.
is it possible to use pem file directly in Jmeter to convert to keystore?

As per AccessDeniedException JavaDoc

Checked exception thrown when a file system operation is denied, typically due to a file permission or other access check.

So make sure that the user you're running JMeter from has read access to the keystore file.
You cannot use PEM certificates directly, you need to import them into a keystore using either keytool or OpenSSL tool
For SASL_SSL you will need at least the keystore, truststore can be provided in edge cases, i.e. when you cannot securely connect to the destination endpoint due to self-signed certificates or expired ones or whatever.
More information:

Kafka Authentication with SSL and SASL_SSL
How to Do Kafka Testing With JMeter

